# Allow process to steal focus

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, focus, window-focus

I see a lot of information about preventing a process from stealing focus. My question is quite the opposite: how do I ALLOW a process to always steal the focus when it so desires.

Context:

On a virtual Machine I have window native windows running (like the File Explorer for example, or the desktop itself). Now Process A sometimes want to take the focus. This ONLY succeeds if the focus is currently on either the desktop, a filer explorer or anyother native windows-window. But not if the current focus is something else, like a downloaded game, or tool. Manually I can of course always steal the focus. So I figured it had something to do with the rights of process A.

How can I make sure process A, can always steal the focus.

Occured in windows 7 and 10, running VMWare or VSphere.